# libspotify API: multiple album cover?

Tags: spotify

Given an artist name and an album name, how many cover arts the album could have? I thought it would be only one, but got two album cover arts when searching the artist name "Dire Straits" and album name "Brothers In Arms".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One album has one album cover. However, there may be re-releases of the same album that might have different covers. However, one `sp_album` instance will only have one cover.